# Autonomous Localization using AMCL

Tags: localization, navigation, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to get my turtlebot to localize itself automatically instead of me using the 2D Pose Estimate. Is there any way I can make that possible? I am using an RPLidar A2 sensor only.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253701/autonomous-localization-using-amcl/) by [Rayner](https://answers.ros.org/users/28921/rayner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the calling `rosservice call /global_localization`
It will spread AMCL particles all around your map, so once you start moving, or calling `rosservice call /no_motion_update` as mentioned by @achimk, it may converge to your actual position.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0